# Determine the automorphism of ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> Determine the group $\text{Aut}(\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$,where $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})=\left\{a+b\sqrt{2}:a,b\in \Bbb{Q}\right\}$.

First, identity and conjugation which is $a+ib\mapsto a-bi$. But I don't know whether there are some other elements in $\text{Aut}(\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}))$. If we can prove that there is no other element, then $\text{Aut}(\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}))\cong \Bbb{Z}_{2}$.

Comment: Hint: if $\alpha : \Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) \to  \Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ is an automorphism, what can you say about $\alpha(\sqrt{2})^2$? And then what can you say about $\alpha(a + b \sqrt{2})$?

Comment: @RobArthan $\alpha(\sqrt{2})^{2}=\alpha(2)$,$\alpha(a+b\sqrt{2})=\alpha(a)+\alpha(b)\alpha(\sqrt{2})$. So we can say $\alpha(\sqrt{2})=\pm\sqrt{2}$ which tells us there are indeed two automorphisms.Is this observation right?

Comment: yes, that's it.